# How to solve this matrix optimization problem

Tags: optimization, matrix-equations

I am trying to solve this analytically -
find w such that minimize  $ \frac{w'\Omega_1 w}{w'\Omega_2 w}$
Here $ \Omega $ are covariance matrices so invertable and symmetric.

Any idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is called the smallest generalized eigenvalue of the pair $(\Omega_1,\Omega_2)$, or, in your case, simply the smallest eigenvalue of $\Omega_2^{-1/2}\Omega_1\Omega_2^{-1/2}$ (perform the variable change $x = \Omega_2^{1/2}w$ and you have the definition of the smallest eigenvalue.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @Johan. It looks simple enough. Computationally I just need to apply some algorithm that finds square root of the matrix and the smallest eigenvector. The only additional consideration is that the matrices are estimated with sampling error. If its not too much to ask, do you have any recommendation for algorithms?

Comment: I don't know in what context you are working, but there should many linear algebra packages available for you